# Ceasar encryptor completely missing out spaces

Tags: java, math, encryption

I'm trying to code a basic encryptor/decryptor in java with multiple ciphers but I've run into a problem with the ceasar cipher.

It can handle strings with no spaces perfectly fine but if I put a space into the string it will encrypt everything up to the space but nothing after it. I'm probably missing something really basic but does anyone see the problem?

Any tips on coding style would be great too, cheers :D

```
        if (encdec.equals("E")){
        System.out.println("Please input the shift you would like to use :> ");
        int shift = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please input the message you would like to be encrypted :>");
        String encryptionInitial = in.next();
        int len = encryptionInitial.length();
        String s = "";
        for(int count = 0; count < len; count++){
            char c = (char)(encryptionInitial.charAt(count) + shift);
            if (c > 'z'){
                s += (char)(encryptionInitial.charAt(count) - (26 - shift));
            }
            else if (c == ' '){
                s += (char)(encryptionInitial.charAt(count));
            }
            else{
                s += (char)(encryptionInitial.charAt(count) + shift);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Encryption complete :> " + s);


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are reading your message incorrectly: when you call

```
in.next()
```

you read input up to the next space, and drop the rest.

What you need is `in.nextLine()`, but there's a twist: since you just read an `int` before it, you need to drop the first line that you get, and keep the second one:

```
in.nextLine(); // drop
String encryptionInitial = in.nextLine();
```

Perhaps a more robust approach would be to call `nextLine` until you get an input of non-zero length:

```
String encryptionInitial;
int len;
do {
     encryptionInitial = in.nextLine();
     len = encryptionInitial.length();
} while (len == 0);
```

This would work even if the user enters one or more empty lines before the actual message.